# Can I move distribution profile modules from profile folder to sites/all/modules?

Tags: 7, distributions

I just installed a distribution profile and ran `Drush up` to update modules.

I have some problems with the modules located at profiles/somefolder/modules: Drush moved out the old modules but no new modules are added.

Can I move the modules from profile folder to sites/all/modules?

The installation profile is [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart).

Answer (score 2):

If the modules in question are not enabled you can move the modules.

The paths to their location in the system table in the database will be updated when you visit /admin/modules.

However, If they are enabled you may run into issues.

See http://drupal.org/node/183681

Comment: all modules all enabled.

Comment: do drush rr and drush cc all, try them with -v to show any messages. I think you will find that commerce kickstart modules has several dependencies in the profile folder so you wont be able to move everything.

Comment: FYI drush rr is not included by default in drush.

Answer (score 1):

To further complete the prior answer ... As so often in Drupal: there's a module for it ... called "[Registry Rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild)", also mentioned on the link in the prior answers. And it integrates with Drush via the `Drush RR` command.

Basically what you do is to (1) just move your modules to another directory, and (2) Registry Rebuild will then rebuild the system table to get the modules in the right place.

I first learned/discovered it via [DrupalEasy Podcast #133](http://drupaleasy.com/podcast/2014/06/drupaleasy-podcast-133-top-secret-drupal-capital-camp-gov-days), which also explains how this module /drush cmd comes in handy for these kinds of moves.