# Move commerce kickstart 1 to regular drupal base

Tags: commerce

Is there any way to move project under Commerce Kickstart 1 to a regular drupal base?
The answer to [Can I move distribution profile modules from profile folder to sites/all/modules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36075/can-i-move-the-modules-from-profile-folder-to-sites-all-modules) (which seems to be the prerequisite) is negative, but maybe there's another way?

Comment: Moving the files and rebuilding the registry is the only way really - but it's not an exact science, in my experience things usually go wrong

Comment: Be prepared - it will go wrong ;) In theory it should work, but usually things like that does not. But that's just my feeling.

Comment: Thank you for your anwers. I'm not very happy with their content, though ;-)

Comment: That are only comments. It means we are not certain enough about it to post as a real answers. Make backup. And backup of a backup. And try. On a copy.

Comment: Yes, I see the long and winding road ahead ;-0. That's why I'm sort of unhappy. I'll report my "success story" here :-)